# What is the reasoning behind a connection string in a .Net application being read-only

Tags: .net, database

I have come across this problem before and I have never understood the reasoning for it: in a desktop application developed in .Net the connection string is stored as a read-only value in the application's app config.

In **every** windows application I've written, the database needs to be set **by the user**: if I'm deploying an application to different sites it's unlikely they will be using the same database. Surely this is the common case for a desktop application? So why is the connection string made read-only in the framework?

Is it a case of the database framework designers thinking in terms of server applications and forgetting the desktop use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing **requires** that you place your connection strings in app.config. You can use settings files (which are updateable and user-specific), the windows registry, or any datastore you want. In those cases where the database is not configurable, app.config just makes an easy place to define the connection.

What you *SHOULD* avoid is encoding the user's password in the connection string, unless you are using connection string encryption in your config file.

Answer (score 2):

Database connection info in an app.config for a desktop app sounds like a bad idea to me. Typically i would have a desktop app call to a web/wcf service, which in turn calls the DB (this way there is NO connection string stored on the client side)

It's probably a carry over from the way a lot of people do it on the server side.  At least with Web apps, setting the connection string in the web.config file is a nice way to be able to change it without having to recompile.

If you want to allow the user to set thier own connection properties, a string in the app.config might be thought of as a DEFAULT setting.

Comment: Why do you assume that every desktop app would always have access to some web service or WCF service? Many desktop apps are deployed in a stand-alone fashion and may connect to databases on the user's local machine. The strategy by which you acquire a connection string generally depends on the nature of the application itself.

Comment: @LBushkin, You can't run WCF locally?  I didnt ASSUME anything, most of what I posted still applies even for a local DB. If the OP wants his users to select a DB (even if thier only choices are local ones) he STILL negates the need for a readonly setting, would he not?

Comment: My point is that using web/wcf services as a mechanism to deliver settings or configuration to an application seems like overkill - particularly since there are alternative techniques that work just as well. And while you can certainly run web/wcf services locally you need to be able to justify the added complexity and fragility - since now you not only have to manage the configuration of the application, but also the configuration of the service.